# SAPUI5: Detail View Controller - Access Data

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm stuck with my little UI5 app. It's a master/detail app with the according 2 views. I want to get access to the selected data set inside the detail controller. The view and the app itself work. I can display the data inside the detail view.

But I need the data in the controller. I spent hours reading and I'm sure it must be very simple.

Inside the detail controller in the `handleRouteMatched` I defined a new variable `var dataObject = this.getView().bindObject(oPath);`

When I debug the `dataObject` I see that the data is there (but all data not just the selected). It's deep inside the "undefined"
[image: Chrome Debugger Picture]

[image: Chrome Debugger 2]
And I have no clue how to get hold of this. Can someone help?

**EDIT:**

```
var sContext = this.getView().oController.sContext; //Retrieve context
var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel(); // Aquire the model
console.log(oModel.getProperty("/" + sContext + "/Businesstravel"));
```

That's how I finally got it working. It would have been nice to get the whole record though (not only single fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get the object where you have binded the context.
2. get this context, and get the path from it.
3. get the corresponsing data from your model using the path

something like this:

```
var oView = this.getView().byId('DetailPage1');
var sPath = oView.getBindingContext('myModelName').getPath();
var myData = this.getView().getModel('myModelName').getProperty(sPath);
```

#### EDIT

Well I didn't follow all your code, but tested two things that will help you.

First, to get the parameters in your route I use in your detailPage1 Controller

```
onInit: function(){
this.oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
this.oRouter.getRoute("DetailPage1").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
...
},

_onObjectMatched: function(oEvent) {
  var contextFromRouterParameter = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").context;
  console.log('contextFromRouterParameter: ' + contextFromRouterParameter);
},
```

Second, to get your model (you defined it in the manifest, so it is set in the component level) you need to do:

```
var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
```

Wherever you wnat to retrieve it. Then you can use its functions like: `getProperty(sPath)` as I mentioned before

Comment: I think there must be something wrong in the whole model. I can't aquire the oView (it is `undefined`). When debugging it in Chrome I can see the following log: `2018-03-08 14:24:13.721399 Did place the view 'com.sap.build.sap.hrAttrition.view.DetailPage1' with the id 'application-BUILD-prototype-component---DetailPage1' into the aggregation 'detailPages' of a control with the id 'application-BUILD-prototype-component---app--idAppControl' - EventProvider sap.m.routing.Target` so I also tried with the full name without success. And it seems this is also the problem I'm facing in general.

Comment: I tried to skip step1 and just entered `var sPath = this.oView.getBindingContext("dataSource").getPath();` as it seems (I can see in the debugger `oView` is a part of `this`. But again `undefined`. That has been my problem since yesterday. Somehow I can't acquire any of the data in the controller. Something must be wrong in principle (oh and thank you for always helping me :-)) - again, the two views work but I can't access any data in the Detail controller. Only as elements on the detail view.xml

Comment: Can you please add your code? At least, the XML view of your Detail view, the controller of your Detail view, the function that handles the item selection  in your master controller, and the routes definition in your manifest.json file

Comment: Good day Rafael, I have exported the project from the WebUI into the [zip file](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfgu51862/sharing/HRAttrition.zip). Thank you indeed, it must be a basic error of me.

Comment: Thank you for your help! In fact the second part works and I see all data of the model. Great! As for the first part it works if I do it exactly as you suggested: `contextFromRouterParameter: HRDATA_EMPLOYEESet('4')` that is the log. So using the `handleRouteMatched:` isn't the right place for my coding but `_onObjectMatched:`? Last question: I feel I need to get an understanding of the data model - how did you learn it? Any book recommendation? Or just ingenuity?

Comment: I was a bit too excited, the `var oView = this.getView().byId('DetailPage1');` in `_onObjectMatched:` still delivers `undefined`. I have added the `this.oRouter.getRoute("DetailPage1").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);` in the on_init as per your advise. So far no error in the debugger, just undefined. So progress is: I can get the datamodel (your second advise).

Comment: Yes, `var oView = this.getView().byId('DetailPage1');` won't work in your code, because there is no control inside your view called 'DetailPage1'. I just misunderstood you screenshot at the very beginning. DetailPage1 is the name of your view. You will get your view doing `this.getView()` in the cotroller.

Comment: About my knowledge, well, two years working with UI5... but everything is in the [Demo kit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic)...

Comment: Thank you Sir for all advise. I finally can retrieve the fields with `     var sContext = this.getView().oController.sContext; //Retrieve context
     var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel(); // Aquire the model
     console.log(oModel.getProperty("/" + sContext + "/Businesstravel"));` That is the only way I found. And it works. It would be nice to aquire the whole record and not the single fields but ok.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the whole record'?? Remember to set the answer as valid, clicking the green tic on the left of the answer. This will help others with the same problem